# Is it Possible to transfer a PHP Extension to a other PC?

Tags: php, apache2, virtual-machine, transfer

I have installed Saxon/C PHP Extension on my VM, it was hard to install this exentension, because i dont find a working documentation.

Now the project is finished and we want to publish is. For this we need the extension on our live server.

The question is, it is possible to transfer this extension on the live server. We dont want to destroy anything.

Comment: which os is installed on the virtual machine?

Comment: Linux and the live server to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same Linux distribution on your live machine? If so you can copy the library file for the Saxon php extension. Saxon/C itself can be installed by following the guide here: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html#Installation

Comment: Yes, im using the same Linux distribution, thank you!